# Pass array to function or make sure it is within scope?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array using an onclick function, and I'm getting the error obj is not defined. Maybe it's not within the scope?

js file:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var url = API_URL + "/api/Ticket/GetTickets";
    var data = Ajax.getData(url);
    var obj = [];
    var tickets = JSON.parse(data.JsonResult);
    obj.Tickets = tickets;
    Tickets.Data = obj;

    var viewModel = {
        theObject: [obj.Tickets]
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
function SortColumn(column) {
    obj.Tickets.column.sort();
}
```

Comment: `var obj = {}` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a scoping issue.  Move your `obj` declaration outside the functions, that way it will be visible to both.

Something like this:

```
var obj = []; // <-- move here
function pageLoad() {
    var url = API_URL + "/api/Ticket/GetTickets";
    var data = Ajax.getData(url);
    var tickets = JSON.parse(data.JsonResult);
    obj.Tickets = tickets;
    Tickets.Data = obj;

    var viewModel = {
        theObject: [obj.Tickets]
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
function SortColumn(column) {
    obj.Tickets.column.sort();
}
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure if you're aware, but `[]` is shorthand for an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). If what you're trying to create is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), then you should change your assignment to `var obj = {};`

Answer (score 0):

Of course `obj` is not within scope. It's not in global scope and you aren't passing it into the function.
you can use @smaili's answer as a fix or you can pass `obj` to the function.

```
function sortColumn(obj, column) {
    obj.Tickets.column.sort();
    return obj;
}
```

Then you'll call it with both arguments.

```
var sortedObj = sortColumn(obj, column);
```

[Further explanation of scoping in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/6245553)

Comment: the call to the function is on the aspx page and I don't know if the variable exists over there

Comment: @Jennifer okay. It'll still help to really understand scoping because another function could 'corrupt' variables declared in global scope.